# CakePHP2 virtual field issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm working on my first CakePHP blog project: http://kattenbelletjes.be/
As you can see, there's a footer section that shows the top 25 most popular tags.

There are three relevant tables I use the implement those popular tags:

```
POSTS: id, title, content, slug
TAGS: id, name, slug
POST_TAG_LINK: id, post_id, tag_id
```

I tried to make a CakePHP query via `$this->tag->find`, but there was a persistent SQL error that I couldn't fix.
So, I tried it on the "`$this->tag->query` SQL way:

```
debug($this->Tag->query(
    "SELECT
        Tag.name,
        COUNT(PostTagLink.id) AS count
    FROM
        tags AS Tag
    INNER JOIN
        post_tag_links AS PostTagLink
    ON
        tag.id = PostTagLink.tag_id
    WHERE
        Tag.show = 'Y'
    GROUP BY
        Tag.name
    ORDER BY
        Tag.name ASC"
));
```

The problem is that the output array isn't very nice:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Tag' => array(
            'name' => 'Beauty'
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'count' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Tag' => array(
            'name' => 'Koken'
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'count' => '1'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Tag' => array(
            'name' => 'Lente'
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'count' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'Tag' => array(
            'name' => 'Wonen'
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'count' => '4'
        )
    )
)
```

I want something like this instead:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Tag' => array(
            'name' => 'Beauty',
            'count' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Tag' => array(
            'name' => 'Koken',
            'count' => '1'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Tag' => array(
            'name' => 'Lente',
            'count' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'Tag' => array(
            'name' => 'Wonen',
            'count' => '4'
        )
    )
)
```

Is there somebody with a solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a whole lot easier if you to stick to the CakePHP convention. You could try something like this:

```
  $this->Tag->virtualFields['count'] = "SELECT COUNT(PostTagLink.id) FROM
  post_tag_links AS PostTagLink WHERE PostTagLink.tag_id = Tag.id";

  $this->Tag->recursive = -1; // If you're using join, keep the recursive to minimum in order to keep it optimized.

  $tags = $this->Tag->find("all", 
            array(
                "fields"     =>  array("Tag.name", "Tag.count"),
                "conditions" =>  array("Tag.show" => 'Y'),
                "order"      =>  array("Tag.name ASC"),
                "group"      =>  array("Tag.name")
            )
        );
```

The concept of virtualFields comes into rescue when you want to create customized fields like "count", for eg.

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: Peace to you too :D. I'll try it out, thanks for the help ;)